# What kubernetes version does --generator flag officially deprecated/removed?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I saw from the official author of the deprecating flag that it started to be deprecated on v1.12 referencing here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/68132

Wanted to know the exact Kubernetes version where this --generator flag was officially deprecated/removed. If there is official documentation, please let me know through your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes uses a `CHANGELOG` file for every version released. The newest one is linked at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.25.md.

An easy and practicble approach is to crawl these files "backwards" (as the naming scheme is consistent) and do a full text search for e. g. "generator". You won't have to do that a lot, because the [`1.24` changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md) is already what you need. It says:

> Removed deprecated generator and container-port flags (#106824, @lauchokyip)

So, the flag was removed in `1.24`.